# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'classes_'

Tags: python-2.7, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to calibrate a model trained on 883 classes in keras.

```
# Define model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512,input_shape=(3,),activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(512,activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(883,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(883,activation="softmax"))
```

```
model = load_model("my_model.h5")
calib = CalibratedClassifierCV(model,method="sigmoid",cv="prefit")
calib.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

And I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py", line 163, in fit
    calibrated_classifier.fit(X, y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py", line 345, in fit
    df, idx_pos_class = self._preproc(X)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py", line 312, in _preproc
    transform(self.base_estimator.classes_)
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

model.classes_ doesn't seem to exist, so what have I done wrong?

```
model.classes_
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Why a last dense layer of size 1000 since you have 883 classes?

Comment: you can't pass a keras model to scikit-learn like that

Comment: @desertnaut apologies that was a typo, I have updated the code

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro please can you elaborate? what would you recommend i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Scikit-learn wrapper. Something like this:

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def get_model():
    return load_model("my_model.h5")

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = get_model, epochs=1, batch_size =10)
cv_model = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, method="sigmoid",cv="prefit")
```

https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/

https://keras.io/examples/mnist_sklearn_wrapper/

Comment: After doing that, I try `cv_model.fit(X_train,y_train)` and I get `AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'model'`

Comment: Managed to solve this issue by fitting the KerasClassifier before calibrating the classifier